# Facing multiple errors on identity implementation

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I am trying to implement the identity in my web application. I added the custom user which inherits from the IdentityUser base class. For the roles, I use the base IdentityRole class. I also have DbInitializer to provide some seed data, in case it does not exist in the database.
The project: ASP.NET Core Web APP (Model-View-Controller)
.NET Version: 6

Respective code snippets:

**AppDbConetxt**

```
public class AppDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public DbSet<Actor> Actors { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Cinema> Cinemas { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Movie> Movies { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Producer> Producers { get; set; }
 
    //Order related tables
    public DbSet<Order> Orders { get; set; }
    public DbSet<OrderItem> OrderItems { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ShoppingCartItem> ShoppingCartItems { get; set; }
 
    public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> options) : base(options) { }
}
```

**ApplicationUser**

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    [Display(Name = "Full name")]
    public string FullName { get; set; } //This is the additional property which does not come from the IdentityUser class.
}
```

**program.cs** (*not providing libraries*)

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
 
// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
 
//Adding DbContext configurations
builder.Services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(options =>
{
    //In order to use SQL Server we need to add a new NuGet package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer
    options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("eTicketsConnection"));
});
 
//Service Registration
builder.Services.AddScoped<IActorsService, ActorsService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IProducersService, ProducersService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<ICinemasService, CinemaService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IMoviesService, MoviesService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IOrdersService, OrdersService>();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
builder.Services.AddScoped(sc => ShoppingCart.GetShoppingCart(sc));
builder.Services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>().AddEntityFrameworkStores<AppDbContext>();
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
});
builder.Services.AddMemoryCache();
builder.Services.AddSession();
var app = builder.Build();
 
// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}
 
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseSession();
 
//Authentication & Authrorization
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
 
app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
 
//Seed Data
AppDbInitializer.Seed(app);
 
//Seed User and Roles
AppDbInitializer.SeedUsersAndRoles(app).Wait();
 
app.Run();
```

**AppDbInitializer**

```
public class AppDbInitializer
 {
     public static async Task SeedUsersAndRoles(IApplicationBuilder applicationBuilder)
     {
         
         using (IServiceScope serviceScope = applicationBuilder.ApplicationServices.CreateScope())
         {
             RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager = serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>();
 
             if (!await roleManager.RoleExistsAsync(UserRoles.Admin))
                 await roleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole(UserRoles.Admin));
 
             if(!await roleManager.RoleExistsAsync(UserRoles.User))
                 await roleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole(UserRoles.User));
 
            
             UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager = serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>();
             string adminUserEmail = "admin@etickets.com";
 
             ApplicationUser adminUser = await userManager.FindByEmailAsync(adminUserEmail);
             if(adminUser == null)
             {
                 ApplicationUser newAdminUser = new ApplicationUser()
                 {
                     FullName = "Admin User",
                     UserName = "admin-user",
                     Email = adminUserEmail,
                     EmailConfirmed = true
                 };
 
                 await userManager.CreateAsync(newAdminUser, "Coding123"); //Adding to the database
                 await userManager.AddToRoleAsync(newAdminUser, UserRoles.Admin); //Checks if the user exists in the database and adds the role.
             }
 
             string appUserEmail = "user@etickets.com";
 
             ApplicationUser appUser = await userManager.FindByEmailAsync(appUserEmail);
             if (appUser == null)
             {
                 ApplicationUser newAppuser = new ApplicationUser()
                 {
                     FullName = "Application User",
                     UserName = "app-user",
                     Email = adminUserEmail,
                     EmailConfirmed = true
                 };
 
                 await userManager.CreateAsync(newAppuser, "Coding123"); //Adding to the database
                 await userManager.AddToRoleAsync(newAppuser, UserRoles.User); //Checks if the user exists in the database and adds the role.
             }
         }
     }
 }
```

This is the error message

[image: screenshot of error message in Visual Studio]

I tried to explain the issue I am facing regarding identity implementation in ASP.NET Core MVC. Expect to get the solution how to handle the problem.

Answer (score 1):

In your `AppDbInitializer` for the app user, you may mistakenly used `adminUserEmail` instead of `appUserEmail`. This would create two users with the same email address which can cause an `InvalidOperationException` if you try to retrieve them by email since `FindByEmailAsync` expects there to be only one user per email address.

```
string adminUserEmail = "admin@etickets.com";

// ...

string appUserEmail = "user@etickets.com";

// ...

ApplicationUser newAppuser = new ApplicationUser()
{
    FullName = "Application User",
    UserName = "app-user",
    Email = adminUserEmail, // <-- Maybe it is a copy-paste error. Maybe use it appUserEmail instead adminUserEmail.
    EmailConfirmed = true
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I've changed it but still there is the same error. There is definitely something wrong with the SeedUsersAndRoles method in my AppDbInitializer class.

Comment: Can you provide stacktrace ? @user22868831

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know what's that :| I'll check it later and provide if I can. Thanks for the assistance. Appreciate!

Comment: The error happens in the AppDbInitializer class, on the line: ApplicationUser adminUser = await userManager.FindByEmailAsync(adminUserEmail);
Could it be happening because of the NuGet package versions? All my packages, except Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore, are 7.0.9. I can't update Identity package because I am receiving error saying Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFramework 7.0.9 is not compatible with .NET6